# Proof of 1-particle irreducible (1PI) diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, propagator, 1pi-effective-action, self-energy

If we split the effective action into

$$Γ[Φ] =\frac{1}2ΦiG_0^{-1}Φ + Γ^{int} [Φ]\tag{1}$$

we can show that the full propagator is given by

$$G= i[iG − Σ]^{-1}\tag{2}$$

With

$$Σ=-Γ_{ΦΦ}^{int} [Φ]\tag{3}$$

Here $Γ_{ΦΦ}$ means double functional derivatives   in relation to the mean field $Φ$.

How can we show that  $Σ$ is made of only 1-particle irreducible diagrams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sketched proof:*

1. The full (connected) propagator $$G_c~=~-\Gamma_2^{-1}\tag{A}$$ is (minus) the inverse Hessian of the [proper/effective action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action) $\Gamma$, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/440886/2451).
2. OP's effective action (1) apparently has no tadpole term $\Gamma_1=0$. In this case, the [self-energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-energy)
   $$ \Sigma~=~G_0^{-1}-G_c^{-1}\tag{B}$$
   is an (amputated) 2-pt 1PI vertex, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/440886/2451). $\Box$